# Arduino ESP8266 - Free heap ram goes down with each web page request

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm using Arduino IDE 1.6.8 and ESP8266 Arduino community ver 2.2.0

Every page request the free heap size goes down, until eventually it crashes.

I've seen String class usage on other web serve code so I assume it isn't that..

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

String freeHeap;

WiFiServer webServer(80);

const char* html1 = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1\"/></head><body style=\"background-color:#EEE;font-family:Arial,Tahoma,Verdana;\"><h1>Title</h1>";
String html2 = "";
String req; 

void setup() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin("name","pwd");
  WiFi.config(IPAddress (192,168,1,201), IPAddress (192,168,1,1), IPAddress (255,255,255,0));
  WiFi.softAPdisconnect(true);
  webServer.begin();
}

void loop() {
  WiFiClient webClient = webServer.available();
  if (!webClient) {
    delay(1);
    return;
  } 

  req = webClient.readStringUntil('\r');
  webClient.flush();
  setHTML();
  webClient.print(html1);
  webClient.print(html2);
  delay(1);
}

void setHTML() {
  long  fh = ESP.getFreeHeap();
  char  fhc[20];

  ltoa(fh, fhc, 10);
  freeHeap = String(fhc);

  html2 = "Heap " + freeHeap + "</body></html>";
}
```

Comment: shouldn't you call `webClient.stop()` after you send the page?

Comment: how does webclient free up the memory after being used?

Comment: the loop() has scope, so everything should be dropped each iteration. but something is sticking.. no idea what

Answer (score 2):

Although `WiFiClient` is destroyed at the end of `loop`, the actual TCP buffer living behind it doesn't get free'd until either the client disconnects, or the [TCP MSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_segment_lifetime) limit is reached. Either the browser is keeping the connection alive, or more likely the buffer is kept alive after loop because you (implicitly) destroy the WiFiClient before the client can acknowledge that they received the data correctly.

Per the spec, the ESP has to keep this data around for the entire MSL duration, or until the client says they have received everything correctly. Since this can't happen in your loop, it'll consume RAM until this 2 minute time period is up.

This is easily fixed by waiting until the client has actively closed the connection with some sort of while loop using `client.connected()`, and additionally instructing the browser/HTTP client to close the connection when they are done with the `Connection: close` header. Once it has disconnected, then you should call `client.stop();`

Comment: So that is why i've seen custom headers with 'connection: close', If i were to wait around for the client.connected() to become false in the main loop(), id be blocking other services... or with 'connection: close' are we only talking a few ticks?

Comment: Yes, you would indeed be blocking them. What you can do instead is keep the reference to WiFiClient alive via some sort of other reference - Be it in another class, structure, global, etc - And check it's status (I.e  connected) each time you go through the main loop. If it's disconnected, check for a new client, otherwise wait until that one closes. I'd probably also add some sort of timeout that forcibly closes it as well, in case of an unruly browser - This will incur the ~200 byte penalty, though.

Comment: Another idea, while the loop is blocked by the client, use a Ticker to do other things. https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html